# Connection error to Minecraft in Jelastic cloud

Tags: connection, minecraft, jelastic

In the case of using Jelastic cloud, I want to play Minecraft. The environment is Ok, everything works fine, but I can't connect to my server.
I did everything like in this guide http://blog.jelastic.com/2012/11/08/play-minecraft-in-the-cloud/ 
Maybe I have to do something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to this guide you've created VDS with CentOS. Jelastic provides full [root access](https://docs.jelastic.com/vps) that allow managing your virtual machine in any preferred way.

Now we recommend you to check out opened ports with 
`netstat -nltp`
and firewall configuration with
`iptables -nvL`. Seems like you forget to open necessary port.

In VDS environments in Jelastic ports are closed by default except 22, 80, 443, 8080, 8022. As we know Minecraft server uses 25565 port for external connections.
For opening necessary port for the Minecraft (25565) you should add following firewall rule:

`iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 25565 -m state --state NEW -j  ACCEPT && service iptables save && service iptables restart`.

More information about Jelastic can be found in our latest [release notes](https://docs.jelastic.com/release-notes-43) as well as on our [documentation pages](https://docs.jelastic.com/).

Have a nice day,
Jelastic Support